# How to parse nested json in java

Tags: java, json

I have the JSON structure as similar to below. I want to read the nested value "criteria" object from this JSON, How to parse this JSON in java.

```
{
   "criteria":{
      "LogicalOperator":"copy",
      "Groups":[
         {
            "LogicalOperator":"AND",
            "condition":[
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Shiva"
               },
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"NOT CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Bhangari"
               },
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Shiva"
               },
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"NOT EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Shivanand"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "LogicalOperator":"OR",
            "condition":[
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Ben"
               },
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"NOT CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Hyd"
               },
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Bengaluru"
               },
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"NOT EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Jaipur",
                  
                  "criteria":{
                     "LogicalOperator":"AND",
                     "Groups":[
                        {
                           "LogicalOperator":"AND",
                           "condition":[
                              {
                                 "column":"name",
                                 "Operator":"CONTAINS",
                                 "Value":"Shiva"
                              },
                              {
                                 "column":"name",
                                 "Operator":"NOT CONTAINS",
                                 "Value":"Bhangari"
                              },
                              {
                                 "column":"name",
                                 "Operator":"EQUAL",
                                 "Value":"Shiva"
                              },
                              {
                                 "column":"name",
                                 "Operator":"NOT EQUAL",
                                 "Value":"Shivanand"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am able to read first object "Criteria", but how to do operations on nested objcts("You can see in the json nested "criteria" object).

Java code below which I have tried,

```
//method to retrieve the json file 
public static void getKey(JSONObject json, String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Boolean exists = json.has(key);
        Iterator<?> keys;
        String nextKeys;

        if (!exists) {

            keys = json.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {

                nextKeys = (String) keys.next();
                try {
                    if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        if (exists == false) {
                            getKey(json.getJSONObject(nextKeys), key);
                        }

                    } else if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        String outerLo = String.valueOf(json.get("LogicalOperator"));
                        System.out.println(outerLo);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(nextKeys);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            String jsonArrStr = jsonArray.get(i).toString();

                            JSONObject innerJson = new JSONObject(jsonArrStr);
                            String lo = String.valueOf(innerJson.get("LogicalOperator"));
                            JSONArray result = innerJson.getJSONArray("condition");
                            // JSONArray grpRes = innerJson.getJSONArray("Groups");
                            // System.out.println(grpRes);
                            // List of objects
                            List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                            // Dummy data for testing
                            List<CustomerPojo> list = getCustomerData();

                            System.out.println(lo);
                            for (int j = 0; j < result.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject result1 = result.getJSONObject(j);

                                // Filtering if the operator= "contains for AND Logical Operator
                                if (lo.equals("AND")) {
                                    conditionAND(objList, list, result1);
                                } else if (lo.equals("OR")) {
                                    conditionOR(objList, list, result1);
                                }

                            }

                        // removing duplicate entries from OR Condition
                            if (lo.equals("OR")) {
                                filteringOrConditon(objList);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This Json is not valid because it contains twice an object with key "CG". Neither Java nor any other language will be able to parse it unless you fix the duplicate key.

Comment: how you creating the json ? you can convert duplicates key to list

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: It's not invalid - it just has unspecified behavior. From https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-4: "When the names within an object are not
   unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
   unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
   only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
   object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
   including duplicates."

Comment: @MatteoNNZ : Okay, considering the object key as CG1 and CG2, then how can i parse?

Comment: @shivanandsb if you change the keys, and you wrap it inside a big { ... }. it should become valid Json.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for precising it, I gave my answer based on implementations (I've tested many so far and never crossed one implementation which does not simply throw an error)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: It doesn't cause an issue in Newtonsoft.Json for .NET: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/b0f9c2f8d6f99f0def087ec3fe2f127a

Comment: @JonSkeet nice to know! I use Java and the major implementations just throw an error of duplicate key (like the one of the question above) :)

Comment: I have reframed the question, can anybody help for this questions. Thanks in advance.